# Compare string data between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have two tables TABLE 1 with columns

```
ID Text           email ID
============================
1  This is Test   123@g.com    
2  Make my day    1234@g.com
```

TABLE 2 with one column

```
words(column)
=============    
Test    
trip    
day
```

now wat i want to do is compare the text ( each and every word) from `Table 1` with each row ow word in `TABLE 2`, if found then the id should be logged on a different table.

example: if from `TABLE1`  `Test` is the word which is the row value in the `TABLE 2` word column. so it should log `ID =1` in a different table.

also once the word is found it shouldn't go for further iteration.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
select *
from TABLE1 
join 
TABLE2
on ' '+Text+' ' like '% '+words+' %'
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bb1d/4)

Comment: Thanks... but i did not get any results... just wondering how does this statement work...

Comment: @tulajaramkulkarni: please see the demo , I have included in the answer.( I have used concat function because its mysql engine for sql fiddel )

Comment: Thanks, you demo is clear and explains everything... but i am surprised wat am i missing,, i am using the same query...

Comment: @tulajaramkulkarni: Please not that there is a space  at both ends of the text column (' '+Text+' ').

Comment: ok.. look at this....
select * from Table1 join TABLE2 on ' '+Status+' ' like '% '+ [Blocked list]+'% '

Status is the column on TABLE1 and Blocked list on TABLE2

Comment: select * from Table1 t1 join TABLE2 t2 on ' '+t1.Status+' ' like '% '+ t2.[Blocked list]+' %'

Comment: No Joe ,, still no luck... lastly one thing i observered, when i type Status i do not get the square brackets as i get when i use the Blocked list column, is this something to do with the issue

Comment: Please make sure that the Status column is present in the table... also use like [Status] ..Please put sample data to sqlfiddle.com and show me, if its still not working

Comment: i checked teh Status column is there and also i used [Status].. still not working

Answer (score 3):

This works

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.words
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
ON PATINDEX('%' + t2.words + '%',t1.text)>0
```

**Output**

```
ID  Text            email_ID    words
1   This is Test    123@g.com   Test
2   Make my day     1234@g.com  day
```

Answer (score 1):

You can to use `CHARINDEX` function:

```
select *
from TABLE1 t1
where exists 
(
   select 1
   from TABLE2 t2
   where CHARINDEX(t2.words,t1.text)>0
)
```

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms186323.aspx) to documentation.